# How do I write a has_many :through a scope by a particular ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, scope, has-and-belongs-to-many

My model reads as so :

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :registered_courses
  has_many :courses,  through: :registered_courses
  has_many :sections, through: :courses
```

The problem is that if many different `Registration`'s have the same `Course`. When I write something like :

```
Registration.find(x).sections
```

It returns sections from any registration with the same Course.

But what I really want is all sections *only from that specific registration*. That is, even if other Registrations are using the same Course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get sections which belongs_to specific registration unless your section belongs to registration directly.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. So is there any alternative way to accomplish this though?

Comment: @Trip you can add usual relation has_many - belongs_to between registration and sections, and create relation when any event fired for example courses creation or any other, than you can get what you want. When you take has_many through association, rails work only one way: 1. it find through association models, 2. and then get target association.

Comment: I sort of understand your explanation, but can't visualize the code part.. I'll keep messing around. Thanks!